# How to implement the 4th order Runge-Kutta method with a constraint on a derivative?

Tags: c, math, numerical-methods, differential-equations, runge-kutta

I am trying to solve a set of two 2nd order differential equations using the 4th order Runge-Kutta method. For this purpose, I have rewritten the two 2nd order equations into four 1st order equations, so that the problem gets reduced to solving four 1st order equations. I am writing the code in C language. The two variables in the problem are the radial coordinate (r) and the zenith angle (theta). I expect to obtain a curve like the following:

[The expected plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM6Nf.jpg)

One can observe from the above plot that the derivative of theta changes at the turning points, but the derivative of r never changes its sign because the particle is always moving inwards towards the origin. So, the constraint is: **the derivative of r is always positive**.

I have written the following code where I find that soon after the derivative of theta changes sign, the derivative of r also changes sign and the particle starts to move in the outside direction, and I couldn't implement the constraint in the code. The plot that I obtained is:

[The plot that I obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkBcq.png)

The code that I have written is the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// ***********************************************************************************************

// The integrand for dr/dt 

double integrand1(double R) 
{ 
    return R;
}

// The integrand for dtheta/dt 

double integrand2(double T) 
{ 
    return T;
}

// The integrand for dR/dt 

double integrand3(double r, double theta, double T)
{
    double rnot, a=0.8, l=2.68, r1=3.5, term1, term2, term3, term4, term5, integrand3;       
    rnot = fabs(pow(a,0.125));
    term1 = (r*T*T);
    term2 = (1/((r-rnot)*(r-rnot)));
    term3 = ((l*l)/(2*r*r*r*sin(theta)*sin(theta)));
    term4 = ((3*(r-2)*l*l)/(2*r*r*r*r*sin(theta)*sin(theta)));
    term5 = ((3*r1*a*l)/(r*r*r*r));
    integrand3 = term1 - term2 - term3 + term4 + term5;
    return integrand3;
}

// The integrand for dT/dt 

double integrand4(double r, double theta, double R, double T)
{
    double l=2.68, term1, term2, integrand4;                                               
    term1 = ((r-2)*l*l*cos(theta))/(r*r*r*r*r*sin(theta)*sin(theta)*sin(theta));
    term2 = ((2*R*T)/r);
    integrand4 = term1 - term2;
    return integrand4;
}


// -------------------- THE RUNGE-KUTTA ALGORITHM ----------------------------

double rk4(double t0, double r0, double theta0, double R0, double T0, double t, double h, double arr[])    
{ 
    int n = (int)(fabs((t-t0)/h)); 
    double k1,k2,k3,k4,l1,l2,l3,l4,m1,m2,m3,m4,n1,n2,n3,n4;

    double r = r0;
    double theta = theta0;
    double R = R0;
    double T = T0;

    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) 
        {
        k1 = h*integrand1(R);
        l1 = h*integrand2(T);
        m1 = h*integrand3(r, theta, T);
        n1 = h*integrand4(r, theta, R, T);

        k2 = h*integrand1(R + 0.5*m1);
        l2 = h*integrand2(T + 0.5*n1);
        m2 = h*integrand3(r + 0.5*k1, theta + 0.5*l1, T + 0.5*n1);
        n2 = h*integrand4(r + 0.5*k1, theta + 0.5*l1, R + 0.5*m1, T + 0.5*n1);
        
        k3 = h*integrand1(R + 0.5*m2);
        l3 = h*integrand2(T + 0.5*n2);
        m3 = h*integrand3(r + 0.5*k2, theta + 0.5*l2, T + 0.5*n2);
        n3 = h*integrand4(r + 0.5*k2, theta + 0.5*l2, R + 0.5*m2, T + 0.5*n2);

        k4 = h*integrand1(R + m3);
        l4 = h*integrand2(T + n3);
        m4 = h*integrand3(r + k3, theta + l3, T + n3);
        n4 = h*integrand4(r + k3, theta + l3, R + m3, T + n3);

        r = r + (1.0/6.0)*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4);
        theta = theta + (1.0/6.0)*(l1 + 2*l2 + 2*l3 + l4);
        R = R + (1.0/6.0)*(m1 + 2*m2 + 2*m3 + m4);
        T = T + (1.0/6.0)*(n1 + 2*n2 + 2*n3 + n4);      


        arr[0] = r;     
        arr[1] = theta;
        arr[2] = R;
        arr[3] = T;

//      t0 = t0 + h; 
    } return 0;
} 

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// ------------------
// The main function
//-------------------

int main() 
{ 
    double t0=500.0,r0=50.0,theta0=1.0467,R0=0.0,T0=0.0,t,r,theta,R,T,a,h=-0.001,x,z,arr[4],i,test;

    FILE *fp1=NULL;
    fp1=fopen("rthetaplot.txt","w");


    // Integration

    for(t=499.0;t>=0.0;t-=0.5)
    {
        rk4(t0,r0,theta0,R0,T0,t,h,arr);

        r = arr[0];
        theta = arr[1];
        R = arr[2]; 
        T = arr[3];
        x = r*sin(theta);
        z = r*cos(theta);


        t0 = t;
        r0 = r;
        theta0 = theta;
        R0 = R;
        T0 = T;


        fprintf(fp1,"%f \t %f \t %f \t %f \t %f \t %f \t %f \n", t,r,theta,R,T,x,z);

    }


    fclose(fp1);
}
```

In the code, I have defined the 1st derivative of r and theta as R and T respectively. So, I have four 1st order differential equations for r, theta, R and T. I started to integrate from a point (r,theta,R,T)=(50,pi/3,0,0) and used a negative step-size.

So, can anyone please suggest how to incorporate the constraint that the derivative of r is always positive so that the particle continues to move inwards after crossing the turning points?

Comment: So, you want to avoid `integrand3` to be negative, is it right? Does it make sense, given the original problem, to take the absolute value of it?

Comment: @Bob__ I need to ensure that the 1st derivative of r is always positive, i.e., the integrand1 in the code. The integrand3 is the 2nd derivative of r. I tried using the absolute value of the integrand1 but that is producing error. There is a need to change the algorithm in such a way that the trajectory is towards the origin the moment it crosses the turning point.

Comment: AnnaD, Debug tip: use `"%g"` instead of `"%f"`.  More informative with small values and less noisy with large ones.

Comment: Really want the eighth root here `rnot = fabs(pow(a,0.125));`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, it is the eighth root. But it is a very small value and is not expected to have any effect.